# Devise authentication without password, using just username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Is it possible to set up [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to authenticate without a password?

This is an intranet app. In order to connect to it, you would have to be on the VPN in the first place, plus the app only allows to see the status of orders & history, not submit any information. I guess similar to FedEx or UPS tracking website but allows to user to see the whole account, with an added security of a VPN box the client get from us.

Now I would still require a password, but this is a non-negotiable requirement on the project. Clients are used to this scheme and are not very computer savvy to adjust to a change quickly.

Comment: If it's too complicated (and I'm not so familiar with Devise), you could just make the password a hidden form element.

Comment: slhck, I could. And I could just setup all accounts with some dummy password and submit it in the hidden field, but what's the fun in that? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The not-so-elegant solution (that doesn't require Devise modification): use a default password that is identical for all users

Use a `before_validation` callback to set `user.password` and `user.password_confirmation` to a default value (e.g. `password`).

Generate the Devise views with `rails generate devise:views`

Modify sign in form to add a hidden password field with your default password value.

As I said, not elegant, but it should do the trick without needing to dig inside Devise internals.

---

More elegant solution:

Fork the Devise project on GitHub and adapt https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb to your needs

You can then specify your fork in the Gemfile.

Comment: David that's actually in my comment above. I considered that but as you said - not so elegant :-) Thanks anyways, at least I get validated, since I'm not the only one who thought of that :-)

Comment: Updated for more elegant solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I didn't even look at the code, first time using devise, didn't realize it be this simple. thanks.

Comment: Hey, I am also working on the same problem can you shed some light what changes you do ( in database_authenticatable.rb file)to find that  more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, I prefer to monkey-patch `Devise::Strategies::Authenticatable` instead of forking the whole devise repository to make a one line change.

```
Devise::Strategies::Authenticatable.class_eval do
  private
    def valid_password?
      true
    end
end
```

Just place it in an initializer file or at the end of the `devise.rb` initializer (I prefer this because it seems a bit like an additional devise configuration).

To explain, the `valid_password?` patched here usually just returns `password.present?` and is used by `Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable` as an initial validation of the password before actually checking it against the database. Therefore this will only change the behaviour when the password is not provided.

DISCLAIMER: This works so far for me, but is not fully tested so use at your own risk.

Comment: Not working for me in the Rails 7.

Answer (score 4):

This can definitely be done using [sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L33) by including `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` if you're not already inheriting from a `DeviseController` or a controller that inherits from `DeviseController` (such as `Devise::SessionsController`). Then just call `sign_in(user)`:

```rb
class SignInWithoutPasswordsController < ApplicationController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  def sign_a_user_in_without_password
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    sign_in(user)
  end
end
```