# How can I remove a user's password in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to be able to remove a user's password in Devise, so that they have no password afterwards.

In my app, the user sets their password password after they sign-up, and I want to be able to remove the password on a test account so I can easily test the process of setting the password. So there is a user who has a password, and I want that user to not have a password anymore

How can I do this?

Comment: The same question with answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662659/devise-authentication-without-password-using-just-username

Comment: That question is about how to authenticate a user without using a password. My situation is this: in my app, the user sets their password password after they sign-up, and I want to be able to remove the password on a test account so I can easily test the process of setting the password. So there is a user who has a password, and I want that user to not have a password anymore.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `user.update_column :encrypted_password , ''`