# Devise Gem: Login only with email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, rubygems

My question is really simple, ¿How can I authenticate only with the client's email (I mean no password at all)? I know it's a bad practice but it's one of the client's requirements.

Currently I have acomplished to sign up with no password and when it finishes its registration it redirects to the appropiate page (the views with authenitcation required). The problem is that If I delete cookies and try to sign-in it shows "Incorrect login or password"

Currently what I have so far:

**User Model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
   :validatable, :confirmable,:authentication_keys => [:login]

   attr_accessor :login

  def password_required?
     false
  end
end
```

**Application_Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     added_attrs = [:email, :remember_me]
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_in, keys: added_attrs
   end
end
```

**User's Migration:**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_foreign_key :users, :doctores, column: :email, primary_key: :email
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Obviously I alread changed sessions' new view and registration's new view

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662659/devise-authentication-without-password-using-just-username

Comment: Nop I didn't, but I did thinked about that. I was hopping to get a more "elegant" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this wiki article? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up

If the intention here is never to have a password, then take note of the third section - you can override Devise's `password_required?` and `password_match?`

Comment: Yep I already tried it, It just defined it like def password_required? false end and def password_match? true end

Comment: Do you set your users to be auto-confirmed at any point in the signup flow? Do they manually confirm? Do you need the `confirmable` module?

Comment: Yes I haven't implemented it but I was thinking of doing so

Comment: I suppose you could override `valid_password?` to always return `true`  (see source here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L44)... It might also be worth reconsidering whether you need Devise at all :-)

Comment: I guess your right I will make a simple login form. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer is very late. This might gem be a good reference for others facing similar issue https://github.com/abevoelker/devise-passwordless